# MS Access - Calculate

Tags: database, ms-access

I am a student in economics and I don't have much experience in Data Science. I tried to describe the problem as specific as possible, if there is something unclear please let me know :)

I have some problems with data calculations for my final thesis work:

The problem: I want to analyse a data-set with 3 columns and 20 million rows. The 3 columns are timestamp, user(around 130 users) and energy consumption(Watt per second).

[image: Data]

In the example, the data-set is shown. The time stamps are based on intervals of 10-15 seconds and are those timestamps are consecutive. So measurement with timestamp 1458185209 is 10-15 seconds after measurement with time-stamp 1458185109. Those time-stamps are anonymously generated. However,I know the exact begin- and end-time and date of measurements. There are exactly 153 days.

From this information, I want to calculate the average consumption per user per day. Let's say, there are approx. 300.000 measurement points for user1 in the data-set. The total time of measuring is 2 months. So the average consumption of a user can be calculated by taking the average from time-stamp 1 till time-stamp 4918 (300.000/61 days).

I want to do this for all users for all days in the given period.

Another problem is that not all users have the same amount of measurements. However, the measurements can be equally divided over the 153 days. For example, for user1 the first day has 278 measurements and for user2 313 measurements.

In the image, you can see the total measurements and total consumption for the users.

I tried to solve this in Access, but I didn't succeeded so far. I have have any tips or suggestions (preferably in Access), please let me know :)

Comment: this can be done easily using a SQL instruction, if your timestamp is a real timestamp (Unix timestamp for instance) and thus can be converted to a datetime in order to define a time range and to group by day. Answer this first

Comment: Thanks a lot! I converted my Unix timestamps to a datetime and now I will be able to finish it :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that where not all users have the same number of measurements, that they used no power? That would be easy to tell if there are no records with zero consumption.

To help understand the intervals and how to convert to something that makes sense, take a look at the following code. All you would need to do in Access is to calculate the date/time as: DateAdd("s", Timestamp, #1/1/1970#)

```
Function Date_Timestamp()

' Timestamp should be # of seconds since 1/1/1970

Dim lTimestamp  As Long
Dim dStartDate  As Date
Dim dThisDate   As Date
Dim lSecPerMin  As Long
Dim lSecPerHr   As Long
Dim lSecPerDay  As Long
Dim lSecPerYr   As Long
Dim lNbrDays    As Long

dStartDate = #1/1/1970#

lTimestamp = 1460210005
lSecPerMin = 60
lSecPerHr = 60 * lSecPerMin     ' =      3,600
lSecPerDay = 24 * lSecPerHr     ' =     86,400
lSecPerYr = 365 * lSecPerDay    ' = 31,536,000      ** Don't use this (Leap Years!!)
lNbrDays = lTimestamp / lSecPerDay

' Just show the approximate date...
dThisDate = DateAdd("d", lNbrDays, #1/1/1970#)
Debug.Print "Timestamp: " & lTimestamp & vbTab & "# Days: " & lNbrDays & vbTab & "Date: " & dThisDate

' To be more precise, show the time also...
dThisDate = DateAdd("s", lTimestamp, #1/1/1970#)
Debug.Print "Timestamp: " & lTimestamp & vbTab & "Date/Time: " & dThisDate

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I fixed the problem!